# Getting java ClassNotFoundException for JavaScriptEngine

Tags: javascript, java, linux, ant, intermine

I am getting  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.bsf.engines.javascript.JavaScriptEngine` when executing `ant build-db-userprofile` ([tutorial I'm following](http://intermine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get-started/tutorial/#configure)).

Apparently this is caused when the BSF .jar is not present in `$ANT_HOME/lib` but when I execute `ls -l $ANT_HOME/lib  && ant -version` I get the following:

```
-bash-4.1$ ls -l $ANT_HOME/lib
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 28 May 30 10:03 ant-antlr.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-antlr.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 34 May 30 10:03 ant-apache-bcel.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-apache-bcel.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 33 May 30 10:03 ant-apache-bsf.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-apache-bsf.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 35 May 30 10:03 ant-apache-log4j.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-apache-log4j.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 33 May 30 10:03 ant-apache-oro.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-apache-oro.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 36 May 30 10:03 ant-apache-regexp.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-apache-regexp.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 38 May 30 10:03 ant-apache-resolver.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-apache-resolver.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 28 May 30 10:02 ant-bootstrap.jar -> ../../java/ant-bootstrap.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 38 May 30 10:03 ant-commons-logging.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-commons-logging.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 34 May 30 10:03 ant-commons-net.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-commons-net.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 18 May 30 10:02 ant.jar -> ../../java/ant.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 31 May 30 10:03 ant-javamail.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-javamail.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 30 May 30 10:03 ant-jdepend.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-jdepend.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 27 May 30 10:03 ant-jsch.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-jsch.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 28 May 30 10:03 ant-junit.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-junit.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 27 May 30 10:02 ant-launcher.jar -> ../../java/ant-launcher.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 29 May 30 10:02 ant-nodeps.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-nodeps.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 28 May 30 10:03 ant-swing.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-swing.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 27 May 30 10:03 ant-trax.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-trax.jar
-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$ ant -version

Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on May 10 2016
```

Another possibility that has been mentioned is using JDK < 1.6, but I am using JDK 7.0_79. My ANT_HOME and ANT_OPTS env vars are set as following:

`ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
ANT_OPTS=-server -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx1000m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xms1000m -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=1 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=99`

Comment: Is that softlink active or broken?

Comment: @BhargavKumarR Sorry, I don't follow/understand the question.

Comment: ant-apache-bsf.jar -> ../../java/ant/ant-apache-bsf.jar Is that path valid?

Comment: @BhargavKumarR Oh I see, and yes it is a valid path, that directory also has the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by compiling and installing ant in my home directory. The issue probably happened because of the way the server I'm working on is set up, and the fact that I don't have admin privilege.